# Pagina JSF como retirar a borda de um include

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Gente estou com um problema no visual da minha página JSF.

Detlahes: Tenho uma página que contém um include de uma outra pagina XHTML nela só vai aparecer dados assim que usuario fazer uma interação em alguns dos botões da ( PESQUISAR) tela, assim eu chamo um update no FORM todo.

Problema: Estou usando a tag  <ui:include src="detalheRendimento.xhtml"/> isso faz que essa pagina xhtml já seja renderizada na tela, isso está deixando a visualização feia, como posso arrumar isso para que só aparece o painel assim que tiver alguma interação.

Segue o codigo da pagina pai:

<h:form style="padding-right: 20px;" id="formDadosComprovanteRendimento">

<p:column style="width:80px;text-align: center">
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-search" title="Detalhar"
update="formDadosComprovanteRendimento"
actionListener="#{comprovanteRendimentosMB.detalharRendimento(vo)}">
</p:commandButton>

<ui:include src="detalheRendimento.xhtml"/>

<h:form>

Segue o print da tela de como fica a visualização:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer com que o evento onclick nos botões, altere uma variável global para true.

E o botão que fechar ou atualizar, você altera ela para false.

Em seu xhtml acrescente um if antes de todo o conteúdo

```
<% if(variavel) { %>
```

E completo ao final do conteúdo

```
<% } %>
```